# Change Tensor Product symbol for aesthetically pleasing output

Tags: output-formatting, custom-notation, traditional-form

I'm trying to find a way of keeping an ordered list of subscripted integers which can be outputted in an aesthetically pleasing way to make analysis easier. The idea is to have a list of numbers that can be indexed by any label, not just by numbers.

Here's the code I have been using so far:

```
(* Loading Notation packages *)
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];

(* Creates a subscripted integer *)
fock[n_Integer, m_] := Subscript[n, m]

(* Creates a series of 0's indexed from 1 to nm *)
zeros[nm_] := TensorProduct @@ Table[fock[0, i], {i, nm}]

(* Adds one to any instances of an integer indexed by m in 'in' *)
c[in_, m_] := in /. Subscript[a_, m] -> Subscript[(a + 1), m];
```

Which can be applied as follows:

```
zeros[4] + c[zeros[4],3] + TensorProduct[zeros[3],fock[2,4]]
```

Producing output in `TraditionalForm` looking like:

$$
0_1\!\!\otimes\!0_2\!\!\otimes\!0_3\!\!\otimes\!0_4+0_1\!\!\otimes\!0_2\!\!\otimes\!0_3\!\!\otimes\!2_4+0_1\!\!\otimes\!0_2\!\!\otimes\!1_3\!\!\otimes\!0_4
$$

which is a bit nasty to look at. Whereas I'd rather have it look like:

$$
0_1 0_2 0_3 0_4+0_10_2 0_3 2_4+0_1 0_2 1_3 0_4
$$

To do so natively in Mathematica seems to require using `Times` instead of `TensorProduct`, however since `Times` has the property `Orderless`, the ordering of the indexes is now not maintained.

My question is how can I either: use the `TensorProduct` version without having to see the tensor product (either by using a different function; or by changing the symbol used by Mathetmatica) or use the `Times` version whilst maintaining ordering structure (I could not work out how to modify `Times` or create a function to perform such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't see any need for the `Notation` package here. So I'll just omit that. Also, you need to replace `->` by `:>` in the definition for `c`, otherwise `a` may be polluted by a global value.

The rest can be done as follows:

```
(*Creates a subscripted integer*)
fock[n_Integer, m_] := Subscript[n, m]

(*Creates a series of 0's indexed from 1 to nm*)

zeros[nm_] := myTensor @@ Table[fock[0, i], {i, nm}]

(*Adds one to any instances of an integer indexed by m in'in'*)

c[in_, m_] := in /. Subscript[a_, m] :> Subscript[(a + 1), m];

SetAttributes[myTensor, {Flat, OneIdentity}]

Format[myTensor[x__]] := Row[{x}]

zeros[4] + c[zeros[4], 3] + myTensor[zeros[3], fock[2, 4]]
```

> $$0_1 0_2 0_3 0_4+0_10_2 0_3 2_4+0_1 0_2 1_3 0_4$$

Here I replaced `TensorProduct` by `myTensor` and defined its `Attributes` to mimic those of `TensorProduct`, but with a display format that contains no symbols between the factors.

Comment: Thanks, although how can I use the `RuleDelayed` operator in an expression like: `cs[in_, m_] := in /. Table[Subscript[a_, i] -> Subscript[(a + 1), i], {i, m}]`? If I do replace the `->` with a `:>` all the indexes are left unevaluated to `i`.

Comment: You just have to override the attribute `HoldAll` of `Table` by wrapping the `RuleDelayed` in `Evaluate`. But a cleaner way in this case would be to define the rule as `Subscript[a_, i_] /; 1 <= i <=m :> Subscript[(a + 1), i]`.